# Why do I have to keep authenticating just to scan wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

[image: sdf]

The worst part is that they STACK. Every single rescan requires another password.

And I have two wifi interfaces, doubling the prompts. I went to get coffee and came back to 20 of these prompts.

Can I permanently authenticate?  How do I get rid of all these windows-vista prompts?

Comment: Don't use Windows? This is AskUbuntu.

Comment: ...this screenshot is from ubuntu....

Comment: Consult your System Manager,  ask about WiFi authentication

Comment: i am the system manager, this is my installation on my test box